# Why there is nothing show in this tkinter windows?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk


def abc():
    print('get')


class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.geometry('300x350')

    def bnt(self):
        bnt1 = tk.Button(self, text='j', command='abc')
        bnt1.place(x=0, y=0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```

After i run the code:

I only can see the window without button:

[image: Question picture:]

How can i fix the problem?

Comment: You did not execute `self.bnt()`, so the button is not created.

Comment: @acw1668 where should i add it? in `def bnt(self):` or others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not execute `self.bnt()` inside `__init__()`, so the button is not created and that is why you get a blank window.

Also `command='abc'` should be `command=abc` instead.

Below is the updated code:

```py
import tkinter as tk


def abc():
    print('get')


class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.geometry('300x350')
        self.bnt() # create the button

    def bnt(self):
        bnt1 = tk.Button(self, text='j', command=abc) # changed 'abc' to abc
        bnt1.place(x=0, y=0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```